# Obtener el primer ID libre o desocupado en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de saber el primer registro libre de mysql, pero no el ultimo, si no el **primero libre** que exista.

> Ej:
>
> Tengo registro ocupado 1,2,3,6,7,8,9
> el primero libre seria el 5

de momento tengo un codigo que me dice el ultimo que seria este:

```
$CIdmaxFact = "SELECT MAX(CAST(codfactura AS UNSIGNED)) AS ultimocod FROM Facturas WHERE empresa='".$_SESSION['Empresa_Id']."' AND serie='".$_POST["Infactura_serie"]."' "; //miramos de nuevo el ultimo codigo por si aca
        $RIdmaxFact = mysqli_query($Conectar ,$CIdmaxFact); //pongo un resultado de la consulta
        $DIdmaxFact=mysqli_fetch_array($RIdmaxFact); $idmaxFact = trim($DIdmaxFact["ultimocod"]); $idmaxFact ++;
        $idmaxFact = str_pad($idmaxFact, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Pero no me sirve del todo, ya que solo me dice el ultimo. ¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alguien hizo una pregunta similar [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312101/how-do-i-find-a-gap-in-running-counter-with-sql). Y la [respuesta aceptada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1312137/4955425) propone algunas soluciones interesantes (creo que de allí se inspiró w33haa), aunque no me parece que manejan cada caso correctamente.  Por ejemplo, no va a manejar el caso cuando el código `1` está libre.

Te propongo las soluciones ajustadas siguientes. Para simplificar la consulta, voy a asumir que `codfactura` es numérico, aunque no parece serlo en realidad. Te tocará agregar los casts donde sean necesarios:

```
select codfactura + 1 as proximo_cod_libre
  from (select 0 as codfactura
         union all
        select codfactura
          from facturas
         where empresa = :empresa
           and serie = :serie) t1
 where not exists (select null
                     from facturas t2
                    where t2.codfactura = t1.codfactura + 1
                      and t2.empresa = :empresa
                      and t2.serie = :serie)
 order by codfactura
 limit 1
```

... o, usando `min()` en vez de `order by ... limit 1`:

```
select min(codfactura) + 1 as proximo_cod_libre
  from (select 0 as codfactura
         union all
        select codfactura
          from facturas
         where empresa = :empresa
           and serie = :serie) t1
 where not exists (select null
                     from facturas t2
                    where t2.codfactura = t1.codfactura + 1
                      and t2.empresa = :empresa
                      and t2.serie = :serie)
```

Comment: Funciona genial :) lo unico que no termino de entender muy bien la construcción de la sentencia ni donde meter lo de empresa='".$_SESSION['Empresa_Id']."' AND serie='".$_POST["Infactura_serie"]."'

Comment: Modifiqué la respuesta para agregar las condiciones para empresa y serie. Simplemente reemplaza `:empresa` por `$_SESSION['Empresa_Id']`, y `:serie` por `$_POST["Infactura_serie"]`. Aunque sería preferible que uses una consulta parametrizada en vez de concatenar los valores a mano.

Answer (score 8):

Se puede usar este pequeño "truco"

```
SELECT t.id +1
FROM Table1 t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Table1 t2
    WHERE t2.id = t.id + 1
)
LIMIT 1
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: ¿cuál Table1 t2? solo hay un id en la tabla

Comment: es un otro alias para el Table1 osea table1 tiene 2 alias t y t2.